# How to combine two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 [4] => 6 [5] => 11 )
```

```
Array ( [1] => Zwembad [2] => Airconditioning [3] => Telefoon [4] =>
Internet [5] => Wi-Fi [6] => TV [11] => food )
```

Is there an array function to combine this array to form a new array.

Result Array should be:

```
Array ( [0] => Zwembad  [1] => Airconditioning  [2] => Internet  [3] => Wi-Fi [4] => 6 [5] => TV )
```

That is, the values of First array have been replaced by the values corresponding to the index of second array.

Comment: array_combine() — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have options?

```
$new = array();
$i = 0;
$ak = array_values( $array2 );
foreach ( array_keys( $array1 ) as $k ) 
{
    $new[$k] = $ak[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with array_values

```
$second_array = array_values($second_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_combine.

```
$combineArray=array_combine($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: I tried it. But it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a1 = array("red","green");
$a2 =array("blue","yellow");
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
?>
```

Comment: Please explain your code.